# Reactjs - Should I npm install or add with unpkg - what's the pros and cons

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React-app and would like to use it to develop a small dashboard application for internal use within our corporate team. My back-end is done with ASP.NET with API. My front-end I'd like to use React.js and d3.js.

I see there are 2 ways to get React. First is by installing using npm, then create an app template using npx create-react-app my-app. This puts a lot of modules into my folder, and I have to install node.js, which I feel I may not necessarily need given my backend is done with ASP.NET. The second way is to simply load the reference to the unpkg website using instruction from [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute).

The second method seemed so much easier and I'm tempted to just use just that. I wonder for the more experienced folks out there, what's the pros and cons of using each method, and what I'm missing using one versus another. Thank you.